# how can I clip an <img> inside a <blockquote>

Tags: css, html, overflow

I am trying to limit the horizontal size of whatever I load in a blockquote (I do not control that content in the blockquote so I know it's going to screw up my layout). Here is a reduced testcase of what the page layout looks like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 800px; background-color: #ff0000;">
      <div style="display: table;">
        <div style="display: table-row;">
          <blockquote style="overflow:hidden;">
           <div style="width: 1000px; height: 400px;background-color: #00ff00;"></div>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The size of the blockquote is implicitely set through a width on one of its parent elements and a table container is used to layout the blockquote itself.

Now, if you try to copy/paste the above html into a test.html file, you will see the entire inner div displayed as blue, beyond the boundaries of the red background. I would like to make sure it gets cliped at the background boundaries.

The question is then: is there a way to do this without changing the structure of the html layout and without having to set again an explicit width on the blockquote itself (I cannot do the latter because I do not know the real size of the blockquote in the real layout because there are other elements within the outer div that take an unknown amount of horizontal space) ?

**EDIT**

Earlier, I naively tried the following. I added an extra column in the table to illustrate the fact that I really do not know how much space the other elements in the table will suck up.

```
<html>
  <body>
  <div style="width: 800px; background-color: #ff0000;">
    <div style="display: table;">
      <div style="display: table-row;">
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
          <blockquote style="overflow:hidden;" id="inner">
            <div style="width: 1000px; height: 400px;background-color: #00ff00;"></div>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
          <div style="width:100px; background-color:#0000ff; height: 300px;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var width = document.getElementById('inner').parentNode.offsetWidth;
    console.log(width);
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `overflow: hidden;` to work you have to set the dimensions of the element explicitly.  So, yes, sorry, you have to specify the width on `blockquote`.

If you are allowed to, you can use javascript to determine the width of the parent element which has a set width and then set the width of the `blockquote` accordingly.

Here's an example of how that might work, using your current markup:

```
var root = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0],
    block = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote'),
    i;

for (i = 0; i < block.length; i += 1) {
    block[i].style.maxWidth = root.style.width;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XSwXE/)

However, this would be vastly improved if you were to give the div that's got the set width a class name or id.  Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XSwXE/1/) to see how that would work.

Comment: I am afraid but I have tried to do this rather unsuccessfully already. could you point out how this could be achieved ?

Comment: @mathieu, I have provided a couple of examples of how this could work with javascript.

Comment: I see. My latest attempts were going in the same direction by using maxWidth. If I understand how this code is working, it will make the inner blockquote clip its content to the size of the outer fixed-size width div. This is not exactly what I am after because I want the inner blockquote to leave some space for the other columns in the table. i.e., the other columns should take their "natural" minimum size, leave whatever horizontal space is left to the blockquote and make the blockquote clip its content when it has reached its maximum size as allowed by the maximum width of the table.

Comment: bwaaah. For the record, I eventualy found a solution inspired by the use of max-width for the table-cell that encloses by blockquote. It appears that the css I was working on already knew some kind of maximum width for that column so I derived it and used it in the css directly. Thanks!